# Is there a sound that explodes gunpowder?

Tags: acoustics, explosions

Is there a certain frequency of sound/noise that will cause gunpowder to explode?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a physics question.

Comment: There is no real-world speaker and real-world sound that can make such things. For example, a similar myth says that a loud speaker can break the windows in a car. This  was debunked experimentally in the 58th episode of Mythbusters http://mythbustersresults.com/episode58 that I saw a week ago. ;-) To make gunpowder burn would require even "louder" sounds. A good frequency doesn't really help because there's no resonance, at least not at frequencies close to what humans can hear (and that's what we call sound). For other frequencies, the required intensity would be superhuge.

Comment: Would the use of "sound bullets" work to explode gunpowder bullets? http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/apl/104/1/10.1063/1.4857635

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, let's experiment.  In your house, not mine!

First of all, gunpowder doesn't explode - it burns. The explosion occurs when it's in a confined region such as a rifle cartridge or packed firecracker.

Next, it's possible, tho' unlikely that there's a resonant frequency in gunpowder analogous to water molecules' resonance at microwave frequencies.

And finally, if you beam enough acoustic power into a pile of gunpowder it'll just plain heat up until it ignites.  Probably other bad things will happen first like going deaf.

Comment: Yep there are lots of videos of bullets in microwave ovens on the internet but that is not sound, it's light.

Comment: "Sometimes, microwave heating is explained as a resonance of water molecules, but this is incorrect;[14] such resonances occur only at above 1 terahertz (THz)." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven

Comment: @Jitter: No - it is not light, but microwaves - hence the name *microwave oven*. Microwaves and light are both electromagnetic waves.

Comment: There are people who put bullets in microwave ovens?